# How to write this logic of complex conditions to iterate and filter a collection/list of objects with a foreach?

Tags: c#, list, foreach, collections, conditional-statements

I have a `ConstructionsetTemp` object having structure like as below:

```
public class ConstructionSetTemp
{           
    public string massing_type { get; set; }
    public double above_grade_wall_u_value { get; set; }
    public double roof_u_value { get; set; }
    public double floor_u_value { get; set; }
}
```

And one more object `OpaqueConstructiontemp`:

```
public class OpaqueConstructionTemp
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string intended_surface_type { get; set; }
    public string outside { get; set; }
    public string layer_2 { get; set; }
}
```

I am extracting the data from excel sheet and forming an db entity object and storing it in the db. The excel sheet data for ConstructionSetTemp like as below

[image]

and the below data is for OpaqueConstructionTemp
[image]

For each row in `ConstructionsetTemp` table I am adding `OpaqueConstructionTemp` as a list of objects.

I have one condition where i need to skip one or other rows in OpaqueConstructionTemp while adding those to constructionsetTemp. The condition is based on intended surface type and name of the OpaqueConstructionTemp and massing_type from the ConstructionSetTemp

**Condition 1** : if massing type and name of the OpaqueConstructionTemp contains `steel` and intended surface type is  `exterior` i need to go with the second row as shown in the second image and need to skip the third row

**Condition 2** : if massing type and name of the OpaqueConstructionTemp contains `mass` and intended surface type is  `exterior` i need to go with the third row as shown in the second image and need to skip the second row from adding to list of `OpaqueConstructionTemp`

Below is the code where i am looping through first list object `ConstructionSetTemp` and other one `OpaqueConstructionTemp`

```
foreach (var constructionSetTemp in constructionSetData)
{
    string massingType = constructionSetTemp.massing_type;
    foreach (var opaqueConstructionDataTemp in opaqueConstructionData)
    {
        string name = opaqueConstructionDataTemp.name;
        string intended_surface_type = opaqueConstructionDataTemp.intended_surface_type
        // here i need to skip the rows based on these variables
    }
}
```

I know i can use `continue` to skip the current row and execute the next row but here i need to skip the second row as well based on condition and vice versa.

I don't know how to write the condition statements to skip the relevant rows inside the foreach loop based on the parameter values.

Comment: sorry for the typo, i need to process some calculations inside foreach loop so that is why i used the same.

Comment: I am fine with continue but got confused here on how to use that .. because i need to skip the rows adding to object based on condition

Comment: Ever heard of Linq? It's got the exact functionality you need built right in to dotnet. Take a look at the docs. The answer to your question is there.

Comment: i need to process the `opaqueConstructionDataTemp` inside second foreach loop  and with this how to skip the rows or is it possible if i use linq skip method

Comment: Keep reading the docs, you'll find it. Also this is an A-B problem - you actually want to use Linq to filter out the things you don't want, not to skip anything.

Comment: I am just looking on where to apply the filter because I am using opaqueconstructiontemp inside for each loop

Comment: Hey did you see Linq provides a ForEach function? I think you're focusing too much on the problem with your solution, and not the solution to the original problem, hence the A-B problem.